# Matplotlib PCA sample not working after altering dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pca

I am trying to learn how to use matplotlib.mlabPCA. Below I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA as mlabPCA
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, proj3d

np.random.seed(234234782384239784)

DIMENSIONS = 3

mu_vec1 = np.array([0 for i in xrange(DIMENSIONS)])
cov_mat1 = np.identity(DIMENSIONS)
class1_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec1, cov_mat1, 20).T
assert class1_sample.shape == (DIMENSIONS, 20)

mu_vec2 = np.array([3 for i in xrange(DIMENSIONS)])
cov_mat2 = np.identity(DIMENSIONS)
class2_sample = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu_vec2, cov_mat2, 20).T
assert class2_sample.shape == (DIMENSIONS, 20)

# Combine the two together
all_samples = np.vstack([class1_sample.T, class2_sample.T])
all_samples = all_samples.T
assert all_samples.shape == (DIMENSIONS, 40)

mlab_pca = mlabPCA(all_samples.T)

# 2d plotting
plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[0:20, 0],
         mlab_pca.Y[0:20, 1],
         'o', markersize=7, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='class1')
plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[20:40, 0],
         mlab_pca.Y[20:40, 1],
         '^', markersize=7, color='red', alpha=0.5, label='class2')

plt.xlabel('x_values')
plt.ylabel('y_values')
plt.xlim([-4, 4])
plt.ylim([-4, 4])
plt.legend()
plt.title('Transformed samples with class labels from matplotlib.mlab.PCA()')

plt.show()
```

As you can see, PCA works pretty well and I get the following graph:
[image]

However, when I try to change `DIMENSIONS = 100` (I am trying to simulate spectral data analysis), I am getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols
```

*"Ok sure, I can just apply PCA onto the transpose of this matrix instead." I told myself naively.*

```
DIMENSIONS = 100
...        
mlab_pca = mlabPCA(all_samples)

plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[0, 0:20],
         mlab_pca.Y[1, 0:20],
         'o', markersize=7, color='blue', alpha=0.5, label='class1')
plt.plot(mlab_pca.Y[0, 20:40],
         mlab_pca.Y[1, 20:40],
         '^', markersize=7, color='red', alpha=0.5, label='class2')
...
```

My resulting plot looks completely off! 
[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Or is adding that many dimension actually messing up my data?

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect the points to separate. PCA(X) is not the same thing as  PCA(X.T).T

It seems that requiring numrows > numcols is a limitation of matplotlib PCA. 
Both R's prcomp and Python's [sklearn PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) can take matrices with either numrows > numcols or numcols > numrows.